# Code will print characters but not make a game move

Tags: java, key, keyevent

Hello I am making a program to read chat and if the chat is a certain thing it presses a certain key. I have noticed that the code works, but not when I am in a game. 
CODE:

```
 if (message.equals("up"))
            {
                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();

                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W); // press a
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W); // release a

                } catch (AWTException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I have tried making so that there are more keypresses because I thought it might be the rate that it inputs at is to fast to detect. I am at a lost any help is very welcome!

Comment: Sorry for the full out answer - should be a comment - but why do you have a `robot.keyPress` and a `robot.keyRelease` call right next to each other?? Wont that negate the affect of a keypress?

Comment: Unfortunatley i can't imagine how the game looks like. A possible mistake could be, that the player or the figure moves while a button, in this case 'a', is pressed. So if the keyPress and keyRelease are called right after each other, the time between the two commands is to short to make the player move.

Comment: Never thought about that, is there like a "sleep" command in java? Btw that works, after I get a sleep to then release the key :D

Comment: Thread.sleep(long millis) should do the trick. Don't forget to surround it by a try-catch-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code to wait some period of time between key presses. Keystrokes of that speed will likely be read as 'bouncing'. See this link on [debouncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Debouncing)